# Getting “Failed to login” error while run Ant Migration Tool Target

Tags: deployment, ant, migration, salesforce

I have ant running on my machine and i am trying to run deployment commands in my machine which is failing with below error message.

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/developer/Project/build/build.xml:273: Failed to login: Failed 
to send request to https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/41.0
```

what could be wrong here?

Comment: Is this a sandbox or a dev org? Because the test.salesforce url is just for sandboxes

Comment: Its a sandbox account and found the solution as well. My network firewall was restricting to connect ant with test.salesforce.com. I have to use the proxy and it worked.